# RODBC oracle architecture mismatch with dual clients installed

Tags: r, windows, oracle, rodbc

I'm trying to connect R to an oracle database using the 64-bit client and the RODBC package.

I'm in 64-bit R, and when I try creating a connection get this message:

> "The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application"

I have both 64 and 32-bit oracle clients installed. These two items are in my PATH.

```
C:\Oracle64\product\12.2.0\client_1\bin;
C:\Oracle\product\12.2.0\client_1\bin;
```

Is there any way I can tell RODBC to use the 64 bit client? The documentation says it will scan the path and use the first client it finds with architecture matching the version of R I'm running (and I'm running 64 bit R).

Comment: In case you run a 32-bit application it does not work because it first access the 64-bit version and will fail, i.e. most like crash. Follow this instruction to install 32-bit and 64-bit Oracle client on one machine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately I don't have admin rights on my machine (at work) to make some of these changes. Is there any way I can specify directly in R or RODBC which client it should use since both are installed?

Comment: In order to install an Oracle client you have to be Administrator - there is no exception. Apparently the Oracle clients are not installed properly.